# Visual Studio Word WebAddin won't load

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, project-template

I am trying to make the Word Web Addin project template (that came with Visual Studio) to work.  When starting the project, without modifying anything, I am stuck with the following message :

[image]

I have no clue how to troubleshoot this.  I've searched on google but most stuff with Visual Studio is about VSTO solutions which is not the case here.  Tried both VS2017 and VS2019 with no luck.

Any ideas how to investigate this ?

btw: I'm on Windows version 10.0.14393 with office 2019 / Word version 1911.

Comment: extra info: VSCode word web addins do work and samples in ScriptLab also executes sucesfuly.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell why but after updating my Visual Studio without success, I made a "repair" installation of my VS2019 and it finally worked.